# How to match pattern in a string in SQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, regex

Hi I have a string which is a value of a column in DB.                            "Java (simple) _New=AB_U17484_JAVA00"

I want to write a sql query to check if the string has below

_New={Box1}__{Box2}_{Box3}

Box1 is always two characters only letters, Box 2 is 7 characters only numbers and letters and Box 3 has to match JAVA and any characters after it..like JAVA%

How can i achieve this using regular expressions in sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have six characters in box2 not seven.
So i made it match your example. But if you should match seven characters you can change the box 2 match to `(\w{7})`

But below regex match your provided string.

```
_New=([A-Z]{2})_(\w{6})_(JAVA.+)
```

And you get your matching box 1-3 in group 1-3

hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks Daneil. It worked for me . Is it possivle to acheive the same in Sql query. Actually this text is a value iof a column in database which i need to match

Comment: regular expressions matches text. If you need to do a sql query you simply need to write an sql query to match the values you need from a db.
If the answer is valid for you i would appriciate if you could mark my answer as 'accepted'

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar answer to Daniel's but I have a slightly different interpretation of your spec.

```
_NEW=[a-zA-Z]{2}__[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}(_JAVA).*
```

This regex matches "_NEW=",

then 2 upper OR lowercase letters

then "__" since you need 2 underscores

then any upper/lower alphabet OR digit 7 times (obviously change to 6 if needed)

then "_JAVA"

then any number of anything else, INCLUDING nothing else. Ie: "_JAVA"

Here is [proof/visualisation](https://regexper.com/#_NEW%3D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%7D__%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B7%7D%28_JAVA%29.*)

Comment: Thanks For your response. Would it be possible to do this in sql query?

Comment: That could be possible, although that is out of the scope of this question. You can post another question if you want to have it looked at. (If my response helped you, please make it the accepted answer :)